# jQuery.scrollTop() not triggering $(window).scroll() in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a one page website where links can scroll the page down to an element specified in the hash part of the url. In Firefox & Chrome it works fine, yet when trying it in IE the `scroll` event doesn't seem to be triggered on page load.

This is the code that checks the hash and scrolls to a specific part of the document, this happens in `$(document).ready()`

```
if(location.hash != '' && location.hash != '#!/home') {     
    var obj_id = location.hash.substr(3, location.hash.length);

    $('html, body').scrollTop($('#'  + obj_id).offset().top - 80);
}
```

I've tried forcing it to trigger the scroll by adding `$(window).scroll()` at the end of that code, but that just seems to reset the scroll to 0.

Thanks,

**Edit**

Sorry, I don't think I was making myself clear, but this bit of code technically works fine, but I have a `$(window).scroll(function() { ... });` event handler further on in my script which, when scrolled past a certain point, attaches my header to the top of the page.

Here is that code:

```
var obj = $('#header-background');
var obj_height = $('#header-background').outerHeight(true);
obj.wrap('<div style="width: ' + obj.outerWidth(true) + 'px; height: ' + obj_height + 'px; display: block">');

var top = obj.offset().top - parseFloat(obj.css('marginTop').replace(/auto/,0)) + 20;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(y - (obj_height - 80) >= top) {
        obj.addClass('fixed').css({
            'height': '80px'
        });
    } else {
        obj.removeClass('fixed').css({
            'height': '245px'
        }, 'fast');
    }
});
```

Comment: `location.hash != '#!/home'`  can you double check this bit of ur code why is there a ! after #? also use `try{$('html,body').[....]}catch(e){alert(e)}` should tell you where the problem is, or whats wrong with it. also use `position().top` instead of `offset().top`

Comment: The `#!/` is intentional, it's how I want the URLs to look. I'll have a go at catching an exception. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put some debugging in to see where it is breaking? My tactic on something like this is to first identify how far it is getting with something like:

```
if(location.hash != '' && location.hash != '#!/home') {
    console.log("setting scroll top");
    var obj_id = location.hash.substr(3, location.hash.length);
    console.log("object: %o", obj_id);
    console.log("scrolling to: %s", $('#'  + obj_id).offset().top - 80);
    $('html, body').scrollTop($('#'  + obj_id).offset().top - 80);
}
```

That will help you validate that you're getting something useful from the hash and whatnot. I'm wondering if you're not getting a valid value from $('#'  + obj_id).offset().top

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question as I don't think I was making myself clear on the actual problem. Thanks for the help though.